# Json help needed for newb

Tags: javascript, json

ive written my first ajax script and after a night mare it works perfectly on my local web server, however when i upload to my web host is does nothing. 
ii suspect its because im using getjson and get is dissabled on web host. so its xmas day and i feel very poorly with flu and i need to get this working, could somone help turn this into a post string for me please.

```
xmlhttp.open("GETJSON","lookup.php?sname="+str1+"&reg="+str,true);
```

this is my get but i need to send a post if that makes sense,

```
xmlhttp.open("GETJSON","lookup.php?sname="+str1+"&reg="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

please bear in mind that the most ive done with javascript before now is open windows and go back.
thanks in advance 
nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as `GETJSON` as a request method. Just use `GET`.

Then, use `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)` to parse out the response.